# on Creating zip file all folders from root directory are added

Tags: python, zip

I am trying to zip all the files and folders present in a folder3 using python.

I have used zipFile for this. The zip contains all the folders from the root directory to the directory I want to create zip folder of.

```
def CreateZip(dir_name):
    os.chdir(dir_name)
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile("temp.zip", "w")
    for dirname, subdirs, files in os.walk(dir_name):
        zf.write(dirname)
        for filename in files:
            file=os.path.join(dirname, filename)
            zf.write(file)
    zf.printdir()
    zf.close()
```

Expected output:

> toBeZippedcontent1\toBeZippedFile1.txt
>   toBeZippedcontent1\toBeZippedFile2.txt
>   toBeZippedcontent1\toBeZippedFile1.txt
>   toBeZippedcontent2\toBeZippedFile2.txt

Current output (folder structure inside zip file):

> folder1\folder2\folder3\toBeZippedcontent1\toBeZippedFile1.txt
>   folder1\folder2\folder3\toBeZippedcontent1\toBeZippedFile2.txt
>   folder1\folder2\folder3\toBeZippedcontent2\toBeZippedFile1.txt
>   folder1\folder2\folder3\toBeZippedcontent2\toBeZippedFile2.txt

Answer (score 0):

`walk()` gives absolute path for `dirname` so `join()` create absolut path for your files.

You may have to remove `folder1\folder2\folder3` from path to create relative path.

```
file = os.path.relpath(file)

zf.write(file)
```

---

You could try to slice it

```
file = file[len("folder1\folder2\folder3\\"):]

zf.write(file)
```

but `relpath()` should be better.

---

You can also use second argument to change path/name inside zip file

```
  z.write(file, 'path/filename.ext')
```

It can be useful if you run code from different folder and you don't use `os.chdir()` so you can't create relative path.